# Individual Comment Notification Setting For Post Author

Tags: plugins, comments, author, notifications

Is there a way (Either plugin or custom function), to let every author individually choose, if he/she want's to receive comment notification for his/her posts?

Some of my autors need to receive those messages, others consider them as spam.

Answer (score 1):

I never saw a plugin that does that, but it's interesting. You can create a custom meta field for users, and re-create the function wp_notify_postauthor(); which is the responsible for sending messages to author.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_notify_postauthor

Comment: Thanks! Seems a pretty easy way to do that. I will try and give feedback.